# "both of us" or "pair of us". Are they interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, synonyms

**He is smarter than the pair of us.**

The sentence is from a British parent who is talking about their son and means he is smarter than both of his parents.

I focused on **"the pair of us"** in the sentence, and wondered if it could be a synonym of  "both of us". I have looked up but it does not seem to be common.

My question is: Is "both of us" and "the pair of us" interchangeable?

Comment: In an appropriate discourse, they may well be interchangeable.

Comment: In British English it is also common to hear **He is smarter than the two of us**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they're not interchangeable.

The use of "the pair" suggests that the two are a single unit, as parents often consider themselves. Using "both" instead removes this meaning, so the two are not identical.

Both are grammatically correct and natural.